# DNS resolves wrong IP address in one country

Tags: domain-name-system

One of my friend has an eLearning website based on Claroline. Two days ago, only Switzerland users started to get redirect "randomly" on another IP address when accessing the website domain.

If I force the DNS server to 8.8.8.8 or 9.9.9.9 on the students' PC, the domain is resolved correctly. But if I stay with the local Swiss DNS Server, it resolves to a bad (blacklisted) IP address.

The strange part is: It's not only this one customer and his own computer. Every student based in Switzerland is affected as well. But not French ones.

The second strange part is: Some page responds from this false IP address with the correct content. Like the eLearning was duplicated on another server OR cached somewhere.

The server is an old Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS, and it is probably not correctly protected / configured. I have full access on this server, but I didn't manage it, so I'm not sure what to look for or even what to do.

Here is what I looked at/ tried so far:

- Checked all Apache 2 vhost conf.
- Checked iptables (empty) and `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf` (safe)
- Asked Swisscom (main Swiss telecom) if they blacklisted the domain or something: Nope
  Checked claroline code base: it look safe, but it's huge. I can't check all files.

Here is a nslookup on one of the student Windows computers:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup
Serveur par défaut :   UnKnown
Address:  fe80::8e59:c3ff:fecf:8d9b

> elearning.redacted-domain.ch
Serveur :   UnKnown
Address:  fe80::8e59:c3ff:fecf:8d9b

Réponse ne faisant pas autorité :
Nom :    elearning.redacted-domain.ch
Address:  195.186.210.161
```

And of course, 195.186.210.161 is not the correct IP address of the server.

I'm not a system administrator. I'm just helping a friend, so I'm not sure on what to look next.

Comment: Perhaps it's possible the ISP of those students are attempting to perform some smart caching and so are interfering with the DNS. Are they all at the same university for example? If you utilise HTTPS for your server, then they can still modify the DNS, but the end user would see a certificate error if the DNS result is pointing to a server other than your own as they would not be in possession of the private key.

Comment: Also, are you sure the IP address of the server is static? For example if frequently changing or recently changed within the TTL of the DNS record then it's possible that the DNS is being resolved to an old (once valid IP) - although that wouldn't perfectly explain why they do see mirrored content. If you use a tool such as https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx you might be able to see the TTL of the A record or CNAME record attached to the domain.

Comment: @DavidGoate That's the fun part, students are at home, all over France and Switzerland. The French one doesn't have any problem.

Comment: @DavidGoate Server IP is fix and never changed. https://dnschecker.org/#A/elearning.affis.ch doesn't show any errors.

Comment: Hi, another thing that can happen, as I seen some error like that in the past, it can be a badly maintained DNS server by the ISP. I seen DNS zone that was transfered but never erased at the ISP level, thus leading to strange error.

Comment: While not solving completely the problem, `affis.ch` should be DNSSEC enabled (in which case the ISP would not be able to muck with DNS replies) and you can use DNS over HTTPS or over TLS to bypass the ISP and ISP DNS to make sure it does not listen or modify DNS traffic. After that if the server is on an HTTPS scheme AND you do not have specific CAs installed as trusted that may allow a third party to divert the traffic, then you can be sure to get access to the proper website (or have a fatal irrevocable error and not some redirecting/proxying).

Comment: A comment about security is mandatory, this system is incredibly outdated (ubuntu, apache, php).  Tell the owner it is **urgent to upgrade** everything.  Enable HTTPS (it is free with [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/) and easy with [this tool](https://certbot.eff.org/)) and redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek DNSSEC only helps if the end-users' OSes are enforcing it on lookups, and even then they'll just get a lookup-failed error, which won't be much less opaque than what's happening now.

Comment: @MadHatter I disagree, I really prefer (and prefer to see) a complete failure instead of a success with a modified content without you knowing it has been modified. And of course all security measures are only useful if enabled... Except that a user can use a remote DNS server that does the validation (or fallback to errors) for him (and then you have the issue on what trust do you give to this nameserver, of course)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek and you are free to prefer that, but let's be clear with the OP about the potential benefits of this fix: for any user that even notices it, it'll break everything on your site, all the time.  You write "*the ISP would not be able to muck with DNS replies*", which seems to me wrong: they'll still be able to muck with them, it's just everything will stop working, for no apparent reason, when they do.

Comment: @MadHatter as much as you can hate the fact that you have (for now) no specific error message "DNSSEC failed" (because of no error code for that in the DNS protocol, nor good enough DNS APIs in OS, nor good UI for such security features in applications), I have a hard time understanding how it could be better to be in a situation where things fail sometimes, for some places, not always and partially, instead of just a clear failure at a basic low level. Last case is certainly easier to debug.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I understand you find reliable failure preferable to intermittent failure (you've made that very clear) and you are quite free to prefer it.  I only suggest that we be honest with the OP about the outcomes of mitigation strategies, so **(s)he** can decide which (s)he prefers.

Comment: @MadHatter " for no apparent reason" ?? On the contrary, for a very specific one. You do a DNS query and you get a SERVFAIL back (because of DNSSEC failure, among possible cases), which shows that the server is broken or the domain is locally misconfigured (because of someone changing replies for example) which is easy to debug in one swtich: just add `+cd` to your dig and the result will immediately show if this is a DNSSEC related problem or not. No need to check the OS, iptables, webservers, etc. as the OP did.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek certainly, you and I can both do that.  But if the end-users were that sophisticated, we wouldn't be having this discussion: they'd use public DNS servers, or proxy through a VPN, or tor, or any of about a hundred mitigation strategies available to people with tech clue.  The end-users don't appear, from the question, to fall into that category.

Comment: @MadHatter I do not think we disagree much in fact. If you reread my first comment I explicitely said DNSSEC **and** using DoT/DoH to circumvent lying local resolvers (but just pushing the trust issue onto another spot). Both solutions cater for different problems and even if some try to believe that DoH will now make DNSSEC unneeded, I think we need both.

Comment: @MadHatter +PatrickMevzek Unfortunatly this is not my server nor my client or even my eLearning platform. I'm just a friend who help a friend. But I explained (very clearly!) to the owner that he should update. I'm not making the decision. Thanks for your help, really.

Comment: @iizno keep us posted about what you find.

Comment: @jcaron Seems they choose two different ways to clean this mess. First I helped them to migrate (and patch) the current claroline install on another domain name so students can elearned again. And second, they are looking into a new (up to date) fresh server and elearning platform installation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [MadHatter](https://serverfault.com/a/935035/228986) wrote, this is the end-users' ISP (Swisscom) re-routing your site through a filtering proxy. It is quite probably that all users subscribing to their Internet Guard service are actually proxied through there, not just your site.

[They say](https://www.swisscom.ch/en/residential/security/internetguard.html?campID=BI_GUARD_LINK_IGUARD) that the filter is against malware, phishing and viruses, so it shouldn't be an issue of "classification", but one of security.

Your first step should thus be to check that the site has not been infected. PHP sites tend to be quite vulnerable (if someone finds a way to upload a .php file somewhere in the visible hierarchy, it can then be executed remotely to do anything they want). There are also many other ways to do harm (SQL injections, stored XSS...).

Your home page is not blocked, or at least not all the time, so either:

- only some of the pages are infected
- the infection only shows up a fraction of the time on user requests (a common strategy to fly under the radar)
- or there is something else on some pages that triggers a false positive

You can see the result yourself by pointing the website's address to the IP address of the proxy. You can do that by editing your `/etc/hosts` file (details vary based on platform) and adding a line:

```
195.186.210.161        elearning.affis.ch
```

You can then visit the site as one of those users, and see which pages are blocked or not.

Once you have a better feel of what pages are blocked or not, it might be easier to pinpoint the actual issue. Then fix it, and either it will suddenly go through right away, or you may have to report a false positive (there's a link for that at the bottom of the "blocked" page).

Note that trying to report a false positive before checking for infection would probably be counterproductive. Try very hard to find and fix the issue first.

#### Edit

Note that the version of Claroline you run (1.11.9) has [multiple XSS vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-4753/) known since 2014:

> Multiple cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities in Claroline 1.11.9 and earlier allow remote authenticated users to inject arbitrary web script or HTML via (1) the Search field in an inbox action to messaging/messagebox.php, (2) the "First name" field to auth/profile.php, or (3) the Speakers field in an rqAdd action to calendar/agenda.php

If the issue is indeed a stored XSS attack, take the latest dump of your database and check if it contains anything like a `<script` tag (don't forget to search case-insensitively).

Answer (score 18):

If you point a browser at the IP address returned, http://195.186.210.161/, you get Swisscom's "dangerous website blocked" message.  My guess is that their "safe internet" content-blocking system works, at least in part, by lying in response to DNS requests, and that your website is falling foul of them, for some reason.

I understand that you asked them if they were blocking you, but in my experience even medium-sized ISPs' front-line tech support don't have the slightest idea what's going on out back.  It's quite possible that the whole nanny system is outsourced (or done by a third-party commercial product) and that *nobody* at Swisscom has any idea which sites are blocked at any given time.  Asking your student if (s)he has any kind of "nanny internet" settings on may be more productive.

At the end of the day, this may not be a problem you can solve, since you're not that ISP's customer, and they owe you nothing.  Having the student's parent call their ISP support, complain loudly about wrong DNS resolution, and threaten to change ISP if it's not resolved, is likely to be the only thing that has any effect.

**Edit**: [this thread](https://community.swisscom.ch/t5/Internet/sites-blocked-by-swisscom/td-p/168236) suggests that Swisscom's site blocking engine can be a bit over-enthusiastic, and that it's not always easy to get any kind of positive resolution from them.  It also suggests that this isn't an opt-in filter, but that it applies to all Swisscom customers whether they like it or not, so opting out of it may prove to be difficult.

Comment: That's why I think too but, why are some pages displaying the correct content and other just timed out. ? It's like they duplicate some pages.

Comment: We don't know what they're using, so we can't know how it works.  Maybe the first-line decision is taken at DNS resolution time, but the system at 195.186.201.161 implements a second-line decision based on what URL is requested, proxying through to the real server if and only if it decide the content is "safe".  Once people start trying to bend internet protocols in pursuit of some (unattainable) vision of a "safe" internet, nearly anything can go wrong.

Comment: It seems like a problem that could be solved with a lawyer in the right jurisdiction...

Comment: Could a Competent Sysadmin freelance resolve this issue ?

Comment: (S)he could probably help, but (assuming I'm right about the problem) the issue is at the student's ISP.  No third-party resource can guarantee to be able to fix it.

Comment: If it is actually being proxied and scanned, forcing HTTPS could help (or hurt). The ISP would at least only have the choice of blocking the entire site or none at all rather than blocking some pages and not others. This may make things less confusing for users.

Comment: Would setting up an nginx server to proxy the server in something like AWS and changing the DNS record to point at the AWS server help?  Particularly if https was setup on the nginx server?

Comment: *It's quite possible that the whole nanny system is outsourced (or done by a third-party commercial product) and that nobody at Swisscom has any idea which sites are blocked at any given time.* I worked with a *big* telco that does exactly this, so can confirm. The ISP tech support probably has simply no way of knowing, however they *should* be able to open a ticket to whoever is actually running the classification system if there is any problem.